# How can I import amazon products with synchronisation of inventory with our website for any particular amazon seller?

Tags: amazon-mws

I want to synchronisation amazon products with our website. 
I have used amazon MWS product API, and I get products with any specification of search type, like SKU, SBIN, etc. I don't get all Amazon Products of any particular Amazon seller. Although how to I synchronise amazon inventory  with our site ?

I used MWS report API using report enumeration (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_)
and with a seller others credentials. Although I don't get all products, only i get RequestId.

MWS Repost API Response using ReportType ( _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_ ):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RequestReportResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
  <RequestReportResult>
    <ReportRequestInfo>
      <ReportType>_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_</ReportType>
      <ReportProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</ReportProcessingStatus>
      <EndDate>2018-06-11T18:30:00+00:00</EndDate>
      <Scheduled>false</Scheduled>
      <ReportRequestId>50024017694</ReportRequestId>
      <SubmittedDate>2018-06-12T09:58:21+00:00</SubmittedDate>
      <StartDate>2017-07-02T18:30:00+00:00</StartDate>
    </ReportRequestInfo>
  </RequestReportResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>4c48f34d-4ce1-42e1-bff6-785f8741679c</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</RequestReportResponse>
```

When I used MWS report API using ReportType enumeration(_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_)
and with a seller others credentials. Although I don't get any product inventory synchronised with your local inventory, only i get RequestId.

MWS Repost API Response using ReportType ( _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_ ):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RequestReportResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
  <RequestReportResult>
    <ReportRequestInfo>
      <ReportType>_GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_</ReportType>
      <ReportProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</ReportProcessingStatus>
      <EndDate>2018-06-12T10:13:36+00:00</EndDate>
      <Scheduled>false</Scheduled>
      <ReportRequestId>50025017694</ReportRequestId>
      <SubmittedDate>2018-06-12T10:13:36+00:00</SubmittedDate>
      <StartDate>2018-06-12T10:13:36+00:00</StartDate>
    </ReportRequestInfo>
  </RequestReportResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>29a91881-1fba-40eb-a6a0-213a67c4ed1f</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</RequestReportResponse>
```

Comment: Add relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't get all Amazon Products of any particular Amazon seller**

For that you need to have particular seller's MWS credentials with your developer id.

Once you get seller's MWS credentials (merchantId, marketplaceId, keyId, secretKey, amazonServiceUrl ), you can get all the product using MWS report API using report enumeration (_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_)

To get product inventory synchronized with your local inventory, you can use Order API or report api with _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_ enumeration.